# How to set state as an array and how to access them with setState and this.state

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created an array like this:

```js
state = { arr: [] }
```

I want to update state as well as access them

In my function, I am using want to use it like

```js
func() {
    this.state.arr;   
    // for accesing the array 

    //remaining codes

    this.setState({arr: this.state.arr.push(2)});
    //for updating 
}
```

this is resulting in an error and wrong outputs there is something wrong in the code that has used

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=b): it return new **length** not new array. To get new array you will need to use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=b) that returns new array instance:

```
this.setState({arr: this.state.arr.concat(2)});
```

On the other hand, why would you need `this.state.arr;` for accesing the array? You are not assiginig it to any variable etc.?

Comment: but still  i want to use  is that how we access a state array ? with `this.state.arr`

Comment: is that correct ?

Comment: This is the correct way but you are not using it for anything. So it is basically useless. Please correct me if I am wrong, maybe I am missing something?